# (Ironpython/Winforms) Retrieve value from textbox made in for loop

Tags: c#, python, winforms, ironpython

I am using ironpython and winform to create textboxs in a for loop. I am having issues getting the values of the textbox that were created.

An example is that I am unable to get the value of self.name1.Text when a button is clicked that is suppose to retrieve that value.

```
    import clr
    clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
    clr.AddReference('System.Drawing')
    from System.Windows import *
    from System.Drawing import *
    from System.Windows.Forms import *
    number=7
    class Part1(Form):
        def __init__(self):
            y=0
            #textbox
            for x in range(0,number):
                name="name" + str(x)
                self.name = TextBox()
                self.name.Text=str(name)
                self.name.Location = Point(0,y)
                self.Controls.Add(self.name)    
                y=y+25
            #button
            self.but = Button()
            self.but.Text = "Click me"
            self.but.Location = Point(0, y)      
            self.but.Click += self.but_click
            self.Controls.Add(self.but)
    #button function
        def but_click(self, sender, args):
            MessageBox.Show(self.name1.Text)
    form = Part1()
    Application.Run(form)
```

Why am i unable to get the values of these textboxes, and what do i need to change/add to be able to get them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting `self.name` with each newly created TextBox. Also, later you try to use `self.name1` which doesn't exist. You need to store all the TextBoxes into a list to keep track of them and access them later.

```
self.name = [None] * number
for x in range(0,number):
    name="name" + str(x)
    self.name[x] = TextBox()
    self.name[x].Text=str(name)
    self.name[x].Location = Point(0,y)
    self.Controls.Add(self.name[x])
    y=y+25
```

then later access it through the list

```
def but_click(self, sender, args):
    MessageBox.Show(self.name[1].Text)
```